# Get facebook page id from page access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a application where i am asking for appid, secret and page access token from user. I do not want to ask Page Id. so how can i get Page Id from page_access_token.?

Comment: Debug the token, that should get you the page id.

Comment: @CBroe hi thanks for direction, However i am getting this...```You must provide an app access token or a user access token```. I think may be because i am providing page_access_token

Comment: You need to provide an app or user access token, and it has to be from the app the page token belongs to as well I think.

Comment: @CBroe still cant do that...any other way?.

Comment: Make a simple `/me` request using the page token.

Comment: Thats great,, Thanks a lot,, Why dont you write that as an answer so that other people can get benefit from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not want to ask Page Id. so how can i get Page Id from page_access_token?

You can either debug the access token via an API call - but that would require that the token was issued for your app.

Or you simply make an API call for `/me` using the page access token - that will return the page id.